# Ripple effect position when checkbox button is set to null

Tags: android, android-layout

Ripple effect problem when checkbox button is set to null:

Style used

```
<style name="MyRow">
<item name="android:button">@null</item>
<item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material</item>
<item name="android:drawableEnd">@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:padding">@drawable/dafaultPadding</item>
```

This is the radiogroup containing the radio buttons.

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton style="@style/MyRow"
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:text="@string/someText"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton style="@style/MyRow"
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:text="@string/someText"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton style="@style/MyRow"
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:text="@string/someText"
    />

</RadioGroup>
```

Ripple animation works as expected when the android:button property is set to some drawable.
When null, it has this behaviour on Marshmallow (ripples at the middle of the row).

[Click Here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0k5c.png)

In lollipop works correctly except for the fact that it has no bounds and the ripple expands to the whole window.

The only way to solve this in my mind is to create custom views for each row containing a textview on the left of a radiobutton.
But in this way I will have to create a monster-like controller (to select checkboxes when I press on the textview) and I will lose all the advantages of the radiogroup.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using following style for your radio button:

```
<style name="RadioButton">
    <item name="android:background">?selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/yourDrawablePadding</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/buttonPadding</item>
</style>
```

First of all, `?selectableItemBackground` will fix your ripple problem.

Also use `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle` as your drawable to allow beautiful material animation on checking/unchecking radio button.

You can see the difference below (Google Pixel XL, 7.1.2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Try to set `<item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>` in your style or use custom ripple and set it.

Answer (score 0):

I has same issue with radiobutton, try adding android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_drawable" with android:paddingLeft="10dp" and remove android:drawableRight

Answer (score 0):

set radio button background transparent

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```